# Firebase Firestore rules resource.data not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Can somebody please explain why this rule

```
match /invoices/{id} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
}
```

giving me nothing, but when this:

```
match /invoices/{id} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == 'gkaT45c7gYXCqQpw5al6Fbh9fgC3';
}
```

is working

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of an invoice document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by changing the query and created an index relying on the new query variable